# Requesting specific values from an html input via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to be able to do the following. I want to be able to get certain things from a form. In this case, I only want the "value" field and NOT the "name" field.

```
<div class="searchbox_team" style="margin: 0 0 10px 0; z-index: 50;">
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function customSearch()
    {
         var x = document.customSearch;
         x.replace("customSearch=", "");
         return x;
    }
</script>

    <form name="leSearch" action="/search/node/" onsubmit="return customSearch()" id="search-block-form" class="search-form">
        <input type="text" name="customSearch" value="" id="edit-search-block-form-1" class="searchbox_input" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

I have tried using the following in my function.
`var x = document.customSearch.value;"` but that is not working.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I have attached the following link to see the HTML file that I'm using to locally test this:

[link]http://piratepad.net/NqpVDSCpm3

Comment: There seems to be some highlighting going on within the function -- particularly if I use document.getElementById('foo').value;

Within Notepad++, the "value" is colored differently making me be a bit weary of it's identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, so to get things from the form, you'll want to specifiy like so:

```
document.forms.leSearch.elements["customSearch"].value;
```

EDIT:

try adding a hidden field that stores the value onclick and then get that from the post or get array in your action file.. I think onsubmit call is to blame

`<form name="leSearch" action="/search/node/" onclick="document.getElementById('myhiddenfield').value = customSearch()" id="search-block-form" class="search-form" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="customSearch" value="" id="edit-search-block-form-1" class="searchbox_input" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." />
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="myhiddenfield" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>`

EDIT 2:

I think I figured it out.. the url was appending the field names because it was defaulting to "get" method mode.. set the action=/node/search/" and method="post"

`<form method="post" action="/search/node/" onsubmit="this.action = '/search/node/' + document.getElementById('edit-search-block-form-1').value;">`

Comment: Same issue as earlier. It's still giving me both the name and the value together.

Comment: try adding a hidden field that stores the value onclick and then get that from the post or get array in your action file.. I think the onsubmit call is to blame.. see above

Comment: While it would be easier to do this, I am literally stitching this to a comment field within a drupal content entry. The only thing that I had wanted to do is simply append the inputted text to the action so that the new action would be /search/node/input

Comment: @ProfessorElm Oh you _want_ the action to be concatenated to the input.. in that case dynamically update the action onclick..

`<form onsubmit="this.action = '/search/node/' + document.getElementById('edit-search-block-form-1').value;">`

Comment: As much as I like this solution, the customSearch= is still being appended. Furthermore, the url isn't changing anymore/directing to the /search/node/ location

In other words, what I want to do is to for the user to enter some terms. These terms will be appended to the url redirect | "site action".

Comment: Hmm.. where are you retrieving the value? I don't see how customSearch= could be appended since we never even call that function at this point.. are you adding it serverside in the action file by accident? Maybe from an old test or some such?

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this solution! It indeed seemed to be the case that the post/get behavior was interfering with this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the value of the `input` for `customSearch`.  If so then just use the following

```
var value = document.getElementById('edit-search-block-form-1').value;
```

Your `input` tag already has an `id` value hence the most efficient and simplest way to search for it is using `getElementById`.

Comment: I just gave that a shot and ended up getting search/node/?customSearch=foo

Comment: @ProfessorElm interesting so it's appending the form action to the value?

Comment: Exactly! I'm trying to edit that so that it only displays the value and not the name.

Comment: @ProfessorElm i'm not seeing that. Can you take a look at the following and tell me what I'm doing differently than you? http://jsfiddle.net/vEkDt/

Comment: What is the name of the function within the script? I'm wondering if maybe that's what's causing my mistake...

Comment: @ProfessorElm in my script I'm using an unnamed function. I would definitely change the name of your func as a test